# Is there a way to connect SAP BW/4HANA to Snowflake? (data through Open hub need to push to Snowflake)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sap-bw

Open hub needs to push to Snowflake. I did not find any direct method to push data from SAP BW to Snowflake

Comment: Look at using Snowpipe?  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-rest.html  All you'd need to do is build in the capability on the BW side using API calls.  You can avoid the use of Open Hub completely.

Comment: If you have an Azure instance, there is also an Azure ABAP SDK that allows you to connect to blob storage to dump data.  You could do that and then Snowflake could pick it up.